# DatePicker converters not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, datepicker

I have a DatePicker in a DataGrid.  I also have some converters on the DatePicker.  The converters are not getting fired.  I think it is because the DatePicker has its own validating/conveter.  could some one please help me out?

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RemoteTasks.Controls.TimecardEntry"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Name="uiTimecardEntry"
         d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="550">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/RemoteTasks;component/Resources.xaml"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="uiDataGrid" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TimecardDetailsCVS}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AlternationCount="2" RowBackground="#11000000" RowHeight="30"
              AlternatingRowBackground="#00000000" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#00000000" HeadersVisibility="Column" DataContextChanged="uiDataGrid_DataContextChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150" Header="Date" SortMemberPath="Date">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time" Binding="{Binding StartTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stop Time" Binding="{Binding StopTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hours" Binding="{Binding Hours}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Again, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What values are returned by converter?

Comment: Are any binding errors shown in your output? Where is the `StaticResource` for `DateConverter` declared?

Comment: Actually I got it working.  I'll post it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer to my own question.  This also doesn't override the default converters (like 9/9 would make 9/9/2014).  But when there is a format it doesn't know it fires the event called `DateValidationError` then in code behind, I just call the ConvertBack that is in the converter.  Here's my code:

**XAML:**

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" DateValidationError="DatePicker_DateValidationError"/>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void DatePicker_DateValidationError(object sender, DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var converter = new DateConverter();
    var value = converter.ConvertBack(e.Text, typeof(DateTime?), null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) as DateTime?;
    if (value != null)
        ((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate = value;
}
```

Simple!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `Date` property in your `ItemSource` then try `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your binding, it should work then.

```
 <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```